# How do I fix this error 'ReactRouterDOM' is not defined no-undef?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to using React and have tried multiple import methods including reacreating the react app and am still getting this error message.

I am using HashRouter because I am following a tutorial from a professor however it seems quite outdated and in the video he doesnt show any code on importing. I am unsure if that is what is wrong with the code.

```
    src\index.js
      Line 8:17:   'ReactRouterDOM' is not defined  no-undef
      Line 9:16:   'ReactRouterDOM' is not defined  no-undef
      Line 10:22:  'ReactRouterDOM' is not defined  no-undef
      Line 20:52:  'Home' is not defined            no-undef
      Line 21:58:  'about' is not defined           no-undef
      Line 22:61:  'products' is not defined        no-undef

------------------------------------------------------

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';


function Spa(){
  const Route = ReactRouterDOM.Route;
  const Link = ReactRouterDOM.Link;
  const HashRouter = ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter;

  return(
        <HashRouter>
            <div>
                <h1>Routing - Hello World </h1>
                <Link to="/">Home</Link> --
                <Link to="/about/">about</Link> --
                <Link to="/products/">products</Link>
                <hr/>
                <Route path="/" exact   component={Home}    />
                <Route path="/about/" exact   component={about}    />
                <Route path="/products/" exact   component={products}    />




            </div>
        </HashRouter>
      );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Spa />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

modify below code

```
import ReactRouterDOM, { BrowserRouter, Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

by the way, You don't need to use ReactRouterDom.route，Because you have introduced it by default: Route, Router, Link...